# About the properties of Measure of noncompactness

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let $\alpha$ denote the Kuratowski measure of noncompactness defined on the Banach space $(E,\|.\|)$ and $A, B\subset E$ be nonempty, bounded subsets. Then, 
how to prove that if $A\subset B$ then $\alpha(A)\leq\alpha(B)$?

Answer (score 2):

We say that $S\subset E$ admits $r$-covering, if $S\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_E(x_i,r)$ for some $x_1,\ldots, x_n$. By definition
$$
\alpha(S)=\inf\{ r>0: S \mbox{ admits $r$-convering}\}
$$
If $B$ admits $r$-covering, then so does its subset $A$, hence in evaluating $\alpha(A)$ you take infimum over bigger family of coverings than while evaluating $\alpha(B)$. Taking infimum over larger set always decreases the result, so
$$
\alpha(A)\leq\alpha(B)
$$